# How should I fix this "illegal start of expression" error in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, boolean-logic

I am getting the error:

> Error: (65, 3) java: illegal start of expression

Referring to this line:

```
public boolean equals(WordList wordList)
```

I think this is caused by something with the scope of the string array `WordList[]`. However, it seems that this should be acceptable, as I am calling an instance of a variable in a constructor.

I have tried altering the `WordList[]` construction to `public equals(WordList wordList)`, `boolean equals(WordList wordList)`, and other combinations, although none of these combinations have changed the error message.

Code:

```
public class WordList
{
String[] words;
public int count;

//constructor
public WordList()
{
//create a size two array of strings and assign it to words instance variable
words = new String[2];

count = 0;
}

public int addWord(String word)
{
if(findWord(word) == -1) //word not in list
{
  return count;
}
if(words.length == count)
{
  String[] temp = new String[words.length * 2];
  for(int n = 0; n < words.length; n++)
  {
    temp[i] = words[i];
  }
  words = temp;
}
words[count] = word;
count++;
return count;
}

public void removeWord(String word) //void bc returns nothing
{
int index = findWord(word); // to minimize how many times we call method
if(index == -1)
{
  return;
}

for(int n = index; n < count -1; n++)
{
  words[n] = words[n + 1];
}
words[count - 1] = "";
count --;
return;
}

public int findWord(String word) {
//iterate over each word in current list
//return index of word if found
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  if (words[i].equals(word))
  {
    return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

public boolean equals(WordList wordList)
{
boolean boolEquals;
//override equals method in Object class
//first checks if number of words in each WordList is equal
//if true -> iterate through all words in 1 of lists + 
if(count == wordlist.count)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    if(findWord(words[i]) == -1)
    {
      boolEquals = false;
    }
    boolEquals = true;
  }
}
boolEquals = false;

return boolEquals;
}

public String toString()
{
//provide number of words in a string and then list each word on a new line
String result = "";
result += "There are " + count + " words in the word list: \n";
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  result += words[i] + "\n";
}
return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
}
```

What is causing this error message? I would prefer to keep the constructor and make as few changes to the code as possible to make this a learning experience rather than simply taking the code from someone else.

Comment: This would be much easier to fix with proper tabs.

Comment: If your code was indented sensibly it would be easy to see where the problem lies.

Comment: @Compass how should I do tabs?

Comment: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/ControlFlow/style-if.html

Answer (score 4):

Syntax error - missing } in the method

> public int findWord(String word) {

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing an '}' at line 62...

you should probably replace 'i' by 'n' at line 26 too...

Comment: Thank you, it is fixed now with those suggestions